# How to disable the shadow appearing on Android, when pulling at the top and bottom of a list?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Using React Native, I want to remove this shadow appearing on Android, when pulling at the top and bottom of a list. Is that possible, and what is it called?

I've attached a screenshot that illustrates it below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add this command in scrollview.

```
overScrollMode="never"
```

See look magic shadow is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `showsVerticalScrollIndicator = {false}` in either your ScrollView or FlatList or other listing component.